# display nodes of types on a menu item : drupal 7

Tags: nodes

I have created some nodes of type books and now I want to display some of them on a menu item. How can I do that without using views?

Mome | Books | Atricles |

node type: (Machine name: books)

For example above is my menu structure. And when a user click books it will show some of the books I have created.

Comment: "without using views" will require that you write some code to perform the same task. Have a look at the [module developer's guide](https://drupal.org/developing/modules), and if you're struggling with specific aspects of development we'll be able to help you here

Comment: It Sounds views is the only easy way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Is it just the book name? Like a list of the names and then you can click on it and view more information? In that case, you could just put those book links in the menu itself (if you have a drop-down).

Otherwise, and the more doable option is to just use Views and have it create a page that displays the names of all of the books you've entered.

Is there a reason why you are opposed to using Views to do this?